# конфликт со static

Tags: java, android, libgdx

итак, я рисую imageButton
`

```
    private static ImageButton bb_one;

void create() {

    ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle img_one = new 
    ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
    img_one.up = skin.getDrawable("ae1");
    img_one.down = skin.getDrawable("ae2");
    bb_one = new ImageButton(img_one);

    bb_one.setBounds(camerazero.position.x + 20, 
    camerazero.position.y + 145, 80, 50);
    stage.addActor(bb_one);
}
```

`
дальше при вызове другого метода кнопку необходимо удалить

```
void remove() {
    bb_one.remove(); }
```

в итоге кнопка нормально не отрисовывается, она появляется на долю секунды и пропадает (без вызова метода удаления)

если убрать static, то кнопка будет нормально отрисовываться, но при вызове метода удаления выскочит NullPointerException

пробовал решить через get/set, но все равно вылетал null

Comment: А откуда метод remove знает об имени bb_one, объявленном в методе create?

Comment: поправил немного код :/

Comment: А где вы создаете объект, на который указывает ссылка bb_one?

Comment: не очень понял вопрос
private static ImageButton bb_one;
    bb_one = new ImageButton(img_one);
    stage.addActor(bb_one);

Comment: я придумал как решить костылем, но может есть кто-то с элегантным решением?)

Comment: **static** сразу убирайте.Первое - это потенциальная утечка памяти объявлять ui компоненты с модификатором **static**. Второе - как кнопка может удалить саму себя?(можно конечно сделать так, но...) Удаление UI компонентов добавленных не важно как, динамически или через xml, производится из parent view, в которую вы её добавляли.

**P.S.** Если вы хотите сохранить ссылку на кнопку, не делайте её статической. Если не получается, то добавляйте тэг и обращайтесь к компоненту по тэгу из parent-а там где это нужно.